# How to put a image in top and right?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-image

How can I put a image on top and right of the screen? `With android:layout_gravity="top|right"` only works `right`. The image is on the bottom

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"     android:background="@drawable/image"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:gravity="bottom">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:layout_width="100dp"  
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of `android:gravity="bottom"` , write `android:gravity="top|right"` to your outer LinearLayout